# Job application form submitted after deadline

Tags: job-search, deadlines

There was an on-campus internship opportunity at my college.I got the mail and deadline was 10AM 15
June.I misunderstood it as 10 PM.We had to fill a google form and attach our CV.Nevertheless I submitted after realizing that and the application got submitted.

So should I expect that it would be evaluated because of the workings of the shortlisting that I dont know that they wait or not OR should I forget about it?

Comment: There is no way for anyone on this board to know. It depends how strict the employer wants to be with their deadline.

Comment: "So should I expect that it would be evaluated..."  It shouldn't matter.  You should continue applying to multiple opportunities rather than pinning your hopes on one.

Comment: Sometimes people lockdown the form after the deadline. If it went through, then they did not, so you have a chance. But as Seth said, no one here has any idea if that chance is 1% or 100%. Honestly, this is not a great question for this board since it will be a very specific answer for this job. There is no "industry standard" that would make this question more generalizable.

Comment: They may look at the time of your application and think can't even read the time... Or they may think must of misread 10PM for 10AM and not worry - who can say.

Comment: @Amar Shukla, The best thing you can do is to apply for many positions at many companies. If you are well-qualified, some companies will hire you as fast as they can. Don't worry focus too much on 1 single company. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to know.  But here is the thing - every job you apply for, once you have applied, you should put it out of your mind and move on and keep looking.  Don't apply and hope and wait, and not think of the next one until you know about the current one.  Always move on, and if they respond, deal with it then.